# asp.net core signalR Custom Authentication and tagging connection with custom id

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr, azure-signalr

We are trying to use asp.net core signalR to update client application from the server. Our client will send userId & custom Id in the query parameter when it first creates the connection. We need to check userId & custom Id in the database to ensure those are correct before creating the connection and will return unauthorized response for invalid userId&customid pair. And later we need to find the client searching by custom Id to send message. From [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/authn-and-authz?view=aspnetcore-3.1) I can only see cookie and bearer token authentication. Is there any way of manually authenticate and tag connection for further search?

Comment: Impossible.  How can you verify the userid and custom id before creating the connection.

Comment: In the db there is mapping of userid and custom id. So I can check there. In this link one guy wrote a class HeadersAuthAttribute. I want something like this. So this function will be called before server let the client create connection. Also want to sent property to that client for further search. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38663924/how-to-create-custom-authentication-mechanism-based-on-http-header/38706328

Comment: @Anup you missed the point. Identifying the caller *is* authentication - that's the dictionary definition. That `custom ID` you use is essentially the same as an authentication cookie or bearer token. Except it looks like you intend to never expire it, exposing the app to session highjacking, replay attacks and a lot of other problems mitigated by expiring a session after some time

Comment: Authentication is handled by ASP.NET Core, *not* SignalR. The article you link to simply shows two common options used with SignalR, it's not even about ASP.NET Core authentication. You *can* create custom authentication providers. Check [Overview of ASP.NET Core Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos actually that custom ID is a operation id of that user. When user will be done with that operation custom ID will get invalid. When user starts the operation we save oprtaionid/custom id in the db with userid mapping. We just want to make sure another user can't create this connection by giving his own user id who is not owner of that operation.

Comment: And what you ask is still authentication except `who is not owner of that operation` is *authorization*. Which is also available and takes place *after* authentication. Looks like that custom ID should be treated as a Claim, allowing you to easily restrict access to operations by checking it in code

Comment: We just need to check userid-> customid is correct or not and assign that custom id to that connection for further search. @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: Add a proper authentication mechanism, or use the one you already have to *authenticate the user*. Restricting operations is authorization. Add that Id as a claim to the Identity User and check it in the MVC actions/SignalR operations you want to control. Don't try to build your own middleware when this functionality is already implemented

Comment: Check [IMPLEMENTING USER MANAGEMENT WITH ASP.NET CORE IDENTITY AND CUSTOM CLAIMS](https://damienbod.com/2018/10/30/implementing-user-management-with-asp-net-core-identity-and-custom-claims/). It shows how to add an `Admin` custom claim and authorize a SignalR action based on it. There are other similar questions in SO already